# get path for my .exe

Tags: c#

how can I get my .exe path because if I copy my .exe I can get my new path ?

Comment: Environment.ProcessPath

Answer (score 343, accepted):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

Comment: I only wanted the Path but I see this command gives me path + filename of the exe. :-( On the other Hand GetEntryAssembly().Location gives the path with "file://" - What I needed was `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: This does not work in a Unit Test project.  GetEntryAssembly() is null.

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location returns where the executing assembly is currently located, which may or may not be where the assembly is located when not executing. In the case of shadow copying assemblies, you will get a path in a temp directory. System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase will return the 'permenant' path of the assembly.

Comment: @user799821 You can use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() to get the current working directory.

Comment: `.CodeBase` is better than `.Location`.  `.Location` will take you to the .NET Temporary files directory where your files are copied, if you are using a web application.  If you want the actual location where the files are stored, `.CodeBase` is the better option, and what I, and probably the OP was actually looking for. @Cyrus is right, and I don't think this should've gotten so many upvotes.

Comment: @user799821 Just use `Path.GetDirectoryName` to get the folder without the filename.

Comment: @ProfK:   thanks, that was exactly what I needed.  Full solution worked for me:

`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)`

Comment: This gives you a path with filename, but this: `new FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location).DirectoryName` gives you path!

Comment: `CodeBase` has "file:" prepended to the actual location tho. Just a warning.

Comment: Environment.ProcessPath is better

Answer (score 179):

In addition:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

The first, is the directory of the executable of your application. Beware! It can be changed at runtime.

The second, will be the directory of the assembly (.dll) you run the code from.

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory works in a Unit Test project.

Comment: `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` works for me. The first one has `file;\ ` while the second one provides the absolute file path of the executing .exe. Add `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()` to get the path only

Answer (score 79):

In a Windows Forms project:

For the full path (filename included): `string exePath = Application.ExecutablePath;`
For the path only: `string appPath = Application.StartupPath;`

Comment: "Application.StartupPath will be effected by "Working Directory" if it's set in the exe shortcut, or the process is started from another apps."

Answer (score 4):

in visualstudio 2008 you could use this code :

```
   var _assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly
               .GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;

   var _path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_assembly) ;
```

Comment: That's not really correct answer. It will give you a string like "file://foo"

Comment: Also it will end up with ArgumentException in `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`