# How to get my project path?

Tags: c#, forms, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get path for my .exe using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991933/get-path-for-my-exe-using-c-sharp)

Hello I have a question:
How can I get my root project path? what I mean is the first folder in the project where the solution is.
I found that command :

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

However it gives me a specific path to the release folder:
wanted_Path/bin/Release

So is there other code, should I cut it manually or put my files in the Release folder??

Comment: I think this [**link**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you mean you want the executable path? The project path is only useful for _building_.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the earlier question which was asking for the path to the exe. This one asks for the path to the project!

Comment: Not a duplicate for the reason mentioned by @oefe.

Comment: @oefe nominated for reopening.

Comment: @Oded The project path can also be useful for testing. For instance, there may be data files used for tests that are contained in the project but not part of the build, source code, or distributables.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use

```
string wanted_path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
```

Comment: For me it returns "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared" instead of project path

Comment: that above code is applicable only when you are running it from within visual studio!

Comment: Why don't use System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory ?
It is simpler, easy to read and gives correct path

Comment: @algreat - he is askin for root proj path, whch is at 2 lower level!

Answer (score 102):

This gives you the root folder:

[`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx)

You can navigate from here using .. or ./ etc.. , 
Appending .. takes you to folder where .sln file can be found

For .NET framework (thanks to ***Adiono*** comment)

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"..\\..\\"))
```

For .NET core here is a way to do it (thanks to ***nopara73*** comment)

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "..\\..\\..\\")) ;
```

Comment: How to use `..` or `../..` with `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` ?

Comment: @Stiger: `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"..\\..\\"))`

Comment: I drop here the .NET Core version, in case someone is looking for that: `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "..\\..\\..\\"));`

Comment: in vs2017 15.6 this will return the directory of the executable.

Comment: For those that don't know, if you have a path, you'll use \\ because in C# you escape a \ with a \. Example: `string path = "C:\\temp\\directory\\somefile.png"` will evaluate to `C:\temp\directory\somefile.png`

Answer (score 20):

```
var requiredPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase )));
```

Answer (score 10):

Your program has no knowledge of where your VS project is, so see [get path for my .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991933/get-path-for-my-exe-using-c-sharp) and go `../..` to get your project's path.

Comment: @CharlesB How to use `../..` ?

Comment: Just use it as a relative path, it refers to the project directory