# How to get the path to a folder in my project (and paths to files in that folder)?

Tags: c#

In my project, I added a folder with files in it. They all have a local path.

I want to have a string array with all the paths to all of those files, but I have no clue how to do that.

I tried this, but it only returns strings in the format of "namespace+project+foldername+name".

```
string[] test = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

What I want is the full path:

> D:\Projectname\Project\Folder\file.ext

It would also help to get the reference/path to the folder, because then I could get the files with:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles();
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: string test = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; made it. found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549766/how-to-get-my-project-path

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
string path= Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string[] files= Directory.GetFiles(@"directory");
```

and if you want to get your project directory use

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```