# C# path to certain parent directory

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.directory

Is there a short way to get certain parent directory path from current path.

I have a path like this:

```
"c:\\users\\userName\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\SolutionName\\ProjectName\\bin\\Debug"
```

and i want to get the path to 'SolutionName' directory, like this

```
"c:\\users\\userName\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\SolutionName"
```

I need it because i am storing some data in folder

```
"c:\\users\\userName\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\SolutionName\\DataFolder"
```

and i need to access it from different projects in my solution.

Thank you all, there is what i finished with

```
public static string GetParent( string parentName,string FileName)
    {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

        while (dir.Parent.Name != parentName)
        {
            dir = dir.Parent;
        }
        return dir.Parent.FullName+"\\Data\\"+FileName;
    }
```

I accepted Callum Bradbury answer because i just changed it not to be recursive.

Comment: If you're just trying to access the folder (and not displaying the path), you can simply append ".." to the full path: "c:\\users\\userName\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\SolutionName\\DataFolder\\..\\"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the DirectoryInfo class to do this relatively easily with a little iterative function.

```
    public string GetParent(string path, string parentName)
    {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        if (dir.Parent == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (dir.Parent.Name == parentName)
        {
            return dir.Parent.FullName;
        }

        return this.GetParent(dir.Parent.FullName, parentName);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for, but i changed it so it won't be recursive.

Comment: With your changes if the parentName isn't a parent directory of the current directory, you'll get a null reference exception. Whether that's an issue or not is up to you though. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

if you want a clean solution follow this steps

1. in every project of your solution try to change your `Build` `Output Path`

   [image]
2. you have to make all your paths relative something like this

   ```
    "..\\datafolder\File.txt"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is:

```
var curd = Environment.CurrentDirectory; 
// this will give you current directory for eg: if you are in "Debug" mode then "c:\users\userName\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\SolutionName\ProjectName\bin\Debug" and if you are in "Release" mode then "c:\users\userName\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\SolutionName\ProjectName\bin\Release"
```

now what you want is your path name until `SolutionName` folder which is `3` level up, so all you got to do is append to the above line `@"\..\..\..\"`

i.e.

```
var curd = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\..\..\..\";
```

and you are done.

`Key` the number of level you want to go up from `current directory` the same number of `@"\..\"` you need to append.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few solutions :

```
string dataFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "..\\..\\..\\DataFolder"

string dataFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) + "\\DataFolder";
```

You can also see this link for the best approach to find your current path, it seems like GetCurrentDirectory might not be the best solution : [get path for my .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991933/get-path-for-my-exe)

Comment: I must access same folder from different projects which can be in different folders but all will be placed inside "SolutionFolder", but they can be on different levels.

Answer (score 0):

Create a reg key with path you need

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Names");
key.SetValue("Name", "Isabella");
key.Close();
```

When created, you can use `RegistryKey` class under `Microsoft.Win32` namespace